# Prevent cursor from leaving screen when graphic tablet is turned off

Tags: multiple-monitors, mouse, windows-11, graphics-tablet

Using Win11:

I have 2 monitors: my main one, and a Huion drawing tablet, which is a monitor.

Both are currently setup as the main monitor being the primary monitor, and the Huion tablet extend as a second monitor.

When I use the tablet, this setup is perfect.

When I don't use the tablet, it is turned off, but Windows still detects it, and still try to extend the display to it.

As a result, I often loose my mouse cursor.

I have tried the trick to put the 2 displays corner to corner, which work great until I start using my tablet and as soon as I touch it, the cursor goes on the tablet (which is normal), and from there, I have no way to bring my cursor back to the primary display (which is not touch)

Is there a way to tell Windows 11 not to extend the display when the it is turned off?

Comment: How are you turning off the tablet display? Win+P brings up the Project sidebar that will allow you to choose whether to use any single display, or both in either duplicate or extend modes. Using this should allow you to both disable and turn off the tablet.

Comment: @music2myear With the power button on it. I didn't know about Win+P, will try it in a few hours and report back :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pressing the power button on a screen is really not how you should be "disconnecting" it. Your monitor and computer work together to communicate power states and connection states when you use them correctly.

Use WIN+P to control which screen(s) should be active in a given configuration. When a screen is disconnected, it will turn itself off given its power settings, and of course it will be darkened and windows or your mouse won't be routed to the disconnected display.

Comment: I'll mark it as the best right answer. Ideally I'd want windows to switch between This screen only to Extended when I turn the monitor on, and to revert to This screen only when I turn it off. But it's a workable solution I can live with. Thanks! I learned a new shortcut today!

Comment: Also:  I am not trying to disconnect the monitor, just power it off so Window know I'm not using it and adapt my workspace accordingly.

Comment: But telling Windows not to use the monitor is done by "disconnecting" the monitor using this system. You might want software to behave in some particular way, but that doesn't mean it does work that way. You want things not to be shown, and you want the computer to know not allow that screen space for programs.

Comment: I get what you are saying as far as certain uses, but I fail to see a context in which someone would want to operate a mouse cursor blindly in a screen that is known to be off. (used to be the way I'm describing before)